# ActivityNotFoundException Intents + Widget

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I'm trying to create a Widget which update the text every time I press the save button and get the information from 2 editText. When I press the button to send by Intent the variables it throws

> "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class"

in the logcat. Here my code:

**Main.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button save;
    EditText Nom;
    EditText Cognom;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        Nom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNom);
        Cognom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCognom);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i;
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewAppWidget.class);
                i.putExtra("NOM",Nom.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("COGNOM",Cognom.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**WidgetClass**

```
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static Intent intent = new Intent();

    static String nom = intent.getExtras().getString("NOM");
    static String cognom = intent.getExtras().getString("COGNOM");

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {


        CharSequence widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.TextViewNom, nom);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.TextViewCognom, cognom);

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".NewAppWidget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/new_app_widget_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

Error:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude first thing is you can not start an widget provider like an activity.

If you want update widget widget from activity you can do like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAppWidgetProvider.class);
intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
// Use an array and EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS instead of AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
// since it seems the onUpdate() is only fired on that:
 int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication())
    .getAppWidgetI‌​ds(new ComponentName(getApplication(), MyAppWidgetProvider.class));
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

You can pass your parameter to this intent or better you save your values in [Shared Preference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and use it in your widget provider class in onUpdate method.

I read your widgetprovider class, you will get many errors when using this class. For understanding android widget, you can fork and understand this  [Github sample](https://github.com/arminha/worldclockwidget).

In this sample you  will get how to update widget, how to have multiple widget controls and much more. So i strongly recommend you go through this sample.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

> `AppWidgetProvider` extends `BroadcastReceiver` **NOT ACTIVITY**

```
i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewAppWidget.class);
startActivity(i);
```

To use `startActivity` you need to provide `Activity class's child object`

`NewAppWidget` is not an Activity !!

Comment: Could you tell me the correct way to implement what I want? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is not clear..just simply pass the values to the next Activity..why do u need to create an widget for it ? @Antonio

Comment: or if you want a custom widget..just create it and pass the data to it..in the same activity itself ..

Comment: I just want to edit the widget using the editText values and update it.